# Bash regex finding particular words in a sentence

Tags: regex, string, bash, scripting

I have a sentence like this:

```
"The dog jumped over the moon because he likes jumping"
```

And I want to find all words that match `jump.*`, i.e. `jumped` and `jumping`. How can I do this?

Currently I have the sentence in a variable, `$sentence`. And I know the match word that I want to test against, e.g. `$test` is `jump`.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/\bjump.*?\b/
```

See [here](http://rubular.com/r/tv3ei80kFj). `\b` matches word boundaries and `jump.*?` everything between that starts with `jump`.

In bash you can use it with grep:

```
echo $sentence | grep -oP "\b$test.*?\b"
```

Comment: sorry to comment so late, how do you find the same words, if they are separated by underscores?

Answer (score 4):

#### A Pipe-Free Bash Solution

If you want to do this purely in Bash, you can use the regular expression matching operator and the built-in **BASH_REMATCH** variable to hold the results. For example:

```
re='\bjump[[:alpha:]]*\b'
string="The dog jumped over the moon because he likes jumping"
for word in $string; do
    [[ "$word" =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH}"
done
```

Given your corpus, this correctly returns the following results:

```
jumped
jumping
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $sentence | tr ' ' '\n' | grep "^$test"
```

To be more thorough:

```
echo $sentence | tr '[[:space:]]' '\n' | grep "^$test"
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions

looks like it might help you. (I'm no good at regex or bash, sorry)